# Unable to write to file in jupyter server

Tags: python, jupyter

I have a CSV file in directory : Data -> LabeledData -> annotated_data.csv

I am unable to write to this csv. I get this traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-5496c6fdaf4e> in <module>
     13 # draw_out_path = os.path.join(base_data_path, "AugmentedData", "Draw")
     14 print("here")
---> 15 applyNumberAugmentation(data, washed_path,output, annotated_data)
     16 
     17 copy_tree(output,os.path.join(base_data_path, "LabeledData","Annotation"))

<ipython-input-7-0cbaac3143dd> in applyNumberAugmentation(data, washed_path, output, annotated_data)
    136         for img_file in image_files:
    137             #data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(base_data_path, "LabeledData", "annotated_data.csv"))
--> 138             NumberAugmentation(data, img_file,washed_path, output, annotated_data, "naug-")
    139             print("applying Number Augmentation")
    140 

<ipython-input-7-0cbaac3143dd> in NumberAugmentation(data, file, data_dir, output_dir, annotated_data, index, instance_count)
     20                 fn =str(file).replace(".jpg","")+str('-')+str(index)+str('-')+str(values)+".jpg"
     21                 data = data.append({'#filename':fn,'region_count':3,'region_id':0, 'region_shape_attributes':json.dumps(bb_attributes),'region_attributes':'{"class_type":"Big Box"}', 'digits':label,'digit_length':label_length}, ignore_index=True)
---> 22                 data.to_csv(os.path.join(base_data_path, "LabeledData", "annotated_data.csv"),index = False)
     23 
     24                 SB = get_bb(data, annotated_data,str(file).replace("A_","") , box_class = 'Medium Box')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal)
   3226             decimal=decimal,
   3227         )
-> 3228         formatter.save()
   3229 
   3230         if path_or_buf is None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py in save(self)
    181                 self.mode,
    182                 encoding=self.encoding,
--> 183                 compression=self.compression,
    184             )
    185             close = True

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in _get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text)
    397         if encoding:
    398             # Encoding
--> 399             f = open(path_or_buf, mode, encoding=encoding, newline="")
    400         elif is_text:
    401             # No explicit encoding

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '../Data/LabeledData/annotated_data.csv'
```

I only have access to jupyter server. How do I edit these permissions?

Comment: is your ```base_data_path``` something like ```base_data_path = open('../Data/LabeledData/annotated_data.csv') ``` ?

Comment: please do `ls -l Data/LabeledData/annotated_data.csv` and check if it has write permissions. If not you can add it using `chmod +w Data/LabeledData/annotated_data.csv`